# Date range comparision doesn't include last Date

Tags: javascript, date

I have found a little Javascript function that compares dates and returns `true` when a certain date is within the range of two other dates. It's working fine mostly, but for some reason it returns `false` when the compared date is equal to the end date. It works with the start date though, that's why it's confusing me. Anyone see what I'm missing?

```
var dates = {
   convert:function(d) {
      // Converts the date in d to a date-object.
      return (
        d.constructor === Date ? d :
        d.constructor === Array ? new Date(d[0],d[1],d[2]) :
        d.constructor === Number ? new Date(d) :
        d.constructor === String ? new Date(d) :
        typeof d === "object" ? new Date(d.year,d.month,d.date) :
        NaN
      );
    },
    inRange:function(d,start,end) {
       // Checks if date in d is between dates in start and end.
       return (
        isFinite(d=this.convert(d).valueOf()) &&
        isFinite(start=this.convert(start).valueOf()) &&
        isFinite(end=this.convert(end).valueOf()) ?
        start <= d && d <= end :
        NaN
       );
    }
}
```

---

edit: Here are my inputs: I get my test data from a database, this is the output
http://zoiglapp.bplaced.net/data/selectAll.php
(sorry it doesn't look very pretty, but the important fields are `zoiglBegin` and `zoiglEnd`). As you can see, I have one timerange that ends on 2015-11-09 and one that starts there. The latter one is showing fine, the former one isn't showing up.
This is my AngularJS Controller with the database data, the `today` variable and the compare function I found:

```
app.controller('HomeController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.today = new Date();
    $http.get("data/selectAll.php")
    .success(function(data) {
        $scope.lokale = data;
    });
    $http.get("data/selectCities.php")
    .success(function(data) {
        $scope.cities = data;
    });
    $scope.dates = {
        convert:function(d) {
            // Converts the date in d to a date-object.
            return (
                d.constructor === Date ? d :
                d.constructor === Array ? new Date(d[0],d[1],d[2]) :
                d.constructor === Number ? new Date(d) :
                d.constructor === String ? new Date(d) :
                typeof d === "object" ? new Date(d.year,d.month,d.date) :
                NaN
            );
        },
        inRange:function(d,start,end) {
            // Checks if date in d is between dates in start and end.
           return (
                isFinite(d=this.convert(d).valueOf()) &&
                isFinite(start=this.convert(start).valueOf()) &&
                isFinite(end=this.convert(end).valueOf()) ?
                start <= d && d <= end :
                NaN
            );
        }
    };
}]);
```

and here is where I call the function in the ngIf directive:

```
<div ng-repeat="city in cities | orderBy:'city'">
<h2>{{city.city}}</h2>
<accordion close-others="true">
    <accordion-group heading="{{lokal.name}}" ng-repeat="lokal in lokale | filter:city.city | orderBy:'name'" ng-if="dates.inRange(today, lokal.zoiglBegin, lokal.zoiglEnd)">
        [...]
</div>
```

Comment: what is the input to this function?

Comment: sample input I mean..

Comment: Works ok for me here https://jsfiddle.net/zrqgqfy6/ . So check your input...

Comment: Just tried this: `s = new Date(2015,1,1); e = new Date(2015,12,31); dates.inRange(Date(2015,1,1),s,e); dates.inRange(Date(2015,12,31),s,e);` both returned true... so not sure what your problem is

Comment: @Minato I've edited the post to show my input

Comment: @Linda change ` $scope.today = new Date();` to `var x = new Date(); $scope.today = $scope.dates.convert(x.getFullYear(),x.getMonth(),x.getDate());`

Comment: Since call to `new Date();` renders full **Date and Time** and your converter simply changes to Date + 05:00 GMT depending on the region. so if you change it all the comparisons will be done regardless of what time it is..

Comment: @Minato I put in your Code now but now the entry with today as the start date doesn't show up anymore. So now the complete opposite problem :(

Comment: @Linda change `$scope.today = new Date();` to `var x = new Date(); $scope.today = $scope.dates.convert([x.getFullYear(),x.getMonth(),x.getDate()]);` sorry forgot to put it as array

Comment: @Linda I added the answer to explain what was the issue.. Hope that helps you.. :)

Answer (score 0):

The program is quite correct, but there is a problem with the input you are passing. The input you get from your service is only the date i.e **`d = "2015-11-11"`** converting it to date using `dates.convert(d)` call which internally calls `new Date(d)` since you only pass the date the `Date` object that is returned has an output like **Fri Dec 11 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (PKT)** notice the time in the output that is the case when you only pass the **date string** but **NOT** the **time**. now since you're assigning today like

```
$scope.today = new Date(); //without the arguments.
```

Thee result will in something like **Tue Nov 10 2015 09:44:12 GMT+0500 (PKT)**. Notice the time here. so the **call to `Date();` constructor outputs the CURRENT TIME and DATE**. so when you compare it with the end date **you might be falling SHORT of time** since you might be comparing the **12:00AM or simply 00:00**  being the end time with **XX:XX AM/PM or XX:XX i.e. the current time on the clock** where **XX:XX AM/PM was greater than 12:00AM or XX:XX was greater than 00:00** so it returned `false` on comparison.

There are multiple option you can try one being in the later comment I suggested.

1. First Option

   ```
   var x = new Date(); // This ass usual gives you the current date and time
   $scope.today = $scope.dates.convert([x.getFullYear(),x.getMonth(),x.getDate()]);
   ```

   This call here passes only today's date to the convert function as an array.
2. Second Option a more cleaner one :P

   ```
   $scope.today = $scope.dates.convert((new Date()).toJSON().split("T")[0]);
   ```

   This call will simply split the **time and date** returned and Pass the date only to `convert` call like `convert("2015-11-10")`
3. Third Option is fairly similar to the Second.

   ```
   $scope.today = new Date((new Date()).toJSON().split("T")[0]);
   ```

   this option saves a level of call and a few condition checks. but is bit dirtier IMHO.

## Summary

You can avail your goal by using any of the three options provided Though I'd suggest to use either option 2 or 3 as both are similar but 3rd is computationally efficient.